# Рукавицы — рука, перчатки — ?

Tags: этимология

Рукавицы, понятно, происходят от слова "рука", а от какого слова происходит слово "перчатки"? Да и русское ли оно вообще? Насколько я знаю, перчатки появились не на Руси.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

От "перст" - палец.

*"минимальное количество символов в ответе - 20" 

Боже ж... А минимальное число мыслей?*

Comment: А вот слово *персть* (прах земной) как-то связано с перстами или тут сближение персть-щепоть не катит...

Comment: Я не сталкивался с этим словом. Где вы его нашли?

Comment: Насилу нашел : " 47 (Зачало 163) Первый человек от
земли, перстен: вторый человек
господь с небесе.
48 яков перстный, такови и перстнии:
и яковъ небесный, тацы же и
небеснии:
49 и якоже облекохомся во образ
перстнаго, да облечемся и во образ
небеснаго." (1Кор.15,47-49) Через 'есть' : перстенъ, пестнагw. У меня нет цс-шрифта.

Comment: Насчет минимального количества символов — это не прихоть. Я прекрасно понимаю, что часто хочется спросить или ответить коротко, но надо ведь, чтобы наш форум видели поисковики — иначе как о нем узнают? Отсюда и такие ограничения.

Comment: Да я понимаю, всё нормально.))) Но, право, в тот момент не знал, чем ещё эти символы заполнить, как не самой фразой.

>Через 'есть' : перстенъ, пестнагw, персть. "Прах, земная пыль"  
  
Тогда не знаю, может как-то и связано. Но родственные связи в современном языке утеряны, зацепиться не за что...